# Compiz not loading the Unity plugin since 13.04 upgrade; shows desktop background only

Tags: 13.04

When I log into Ubuntu 13.04, it only shows my background. Now I've tried CCSM to enable the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, but every time I try to do it, it seems to put a check mark in the blank then the check Mark goes away.
 I really need a fix for this because I don't want to have to downgrade my system.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu!  When asking questions it is recommended to use a more descriptive title.  "The 13.04 update is giving me troubles" doesn't say what the question is about.

Comment: The description here of this problem makes it seem identical to the problem described in [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears). You said you tried to enable Unity in CCSM, but there are some other possible solutions in that question as well. Please try all of them if you haven't done so, and edit your question to explain in detail everything you did and what happened. Until then, this still looks like the same issue and this may be closed as a duplicate of that (but even then it can be reopened).

Answer (score 0):

This seems kind of far fetched - but are you sure Unity is installed? If so, it may be worth doing a purge and a reinstall. These can be done from the recovery terminal if necessary.

```
sudo apt-get purge unity && sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Can you provide--or link to--more information about exactly how to do this?

Comment: 'sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop'

Comment: That command won't do what you want. `ubuntu-desktop` is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). Purging and reinstalling it will not cause any of the packages providing actual files for Unity to be uninstalled or reinstalled, and will not make any changes to those packages' configuration files. I'm not sure what the best way is to purge and reinstall Unity, as I believe different parts are provided by different packages (also, `compiz` may be the cause), but if you (or anyone) finds that information, it may be a good idea to *edit this answer* and add it.

Comment: Eliah, generally I have found that metapackages tend to remove some, but not all, packages included. Anyhow, a small subset of ubuntu-desktop is the 'unity' metapackage, which I have used in my edit to my answer.

Comment: If the only operation you specify is to remove a metapackage, then the only other packages that will be removed are *reverse dependencies* of that metapackage (packages that depend on the metapackage). A metapackage's reverse dependencies are almost always also metapackages, so removing a metapackage is very unlikely to cause any actual software to be uninstalled (and purging one is similarly unlikely to cause any systemwide configuration files to be deleted). Successfully removing a *virtual package* often entails removval of actual software; removing a *metapackage* rarely if ever does.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to ensure all the normal desktop packages are installed with a

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I'm not sure why this metapackage would not be installed, but it's worth a try.